# Export List of File Names and URLs

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, export

Using either Powershell or other method, I need to export a list of titles of files, their filenames with extensions, their locations, and their URLs into a text or Excel file. This is what I have found so far (for Powershell):

```
Get-SPWeb https://tenant.sharepoint.com/ |
  Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
    Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq “SPDocumentLibrary” -and
            -not $_.Hidden } |
    Select -ExpandProperty Items |
    Where { $_.Url -like “*Documents*” } |
    Select Name, {$_.File.Length}, url
```

However, I need something that will give me the information I seek and will look recursively. I looked up the `Select-Object` and `-ExpandProperty` in SharePoint documentation, but I couldn't find what my options were for other properties I could choose. Also, I am looking to return all files, not just ones with a specific term in them.

Please help, if you can! Thanks, in advance!

Comment: While a single long pipeline has it's benefits, you loose acces to former stages properties with each select (-ExpandProperty). Either use a `-PipelineVariable` or split by using variables for intermediate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint Online, we can use CSOM with PowerShell to achieve it, the following example Script for your reference.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz"
$ListName="DL"
$ExportFile ="c:\temp\AllFiles.csv"
$UserName="lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="Your Password"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials

#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

#Get All List Items
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">0</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" /></OrderBy></Query></View>'
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$context.Load($ListItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#Array to Hold List Items
$ListItemCollection = @()

#Fetch each list item value to export to excel
$ListItems | foreach {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -value $_["FileLeafRef"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "URL" -value $_["FileRef"]
    #Add the object with above properties to the Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "List data Exported to CSV file successfully!"
```